# key frames based animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

welp.. I used to have css3 animation that worked on my google chrome but for some
reason it stopped working. i tried to create an example based on that code.

I have no clue why it doesn't work anymore.. any information would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
 -webkit-animation-name: bounceup;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceup {
    from {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px) rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 80px #000;
    }
    to {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see it's a keyframes based animation using the 'from' and to' methods.

welp the result here that I just see a red box with no animation what so ever.

thanks!

Comment: Hint: You've only defined an animation name, not the duration.

Comment: i add the animation duration but the only thing that changes is the box shadow... the box doesn't move anywhere until the end of the animation duration

Comment: The box moves fine (Chromium 21.0.1180.89): http://jsfiddle.net/pz89j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the animation doesn't like the order of `translateY(0px)`, so if you move it, it will work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/zJ5A9/